# PHP Regex Replace Subject while keeping case

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, php-7.1, preg-replace-callback

I am using `preg_replace` to swap U.S. words with their British variants in HTML.

```
function makeUK(&$str){

    $delta = [
        'authorize' => 'authorise',
        'center' => 'centre',
        'theater' => 'theatre',
        'capitalize' => 'capitalise',
        ...
    ];

    $pattern = []; $replacement = [];

    foreach ($delta as $k => $val) {

        // match terms using word boundaries excluding "-" character
        $pattern[] = '/\b(?<!\-)'.$k.'\b(?!-)/i'; 

        $replacement[] = $val;
    }

    return preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$str);
}
```

Its a bit crude but fits my use case.

I have the `i` flag set in my pattern to match all letter cases, however this will transmute ("Center" to "centre"), for instance, which is not ideal.

I can add additional values to the `$delta` array to account for capitalized words `"Center" => "Centre"` but this will double the size of the array and a pain to maintain.

I looked into `preg_replace_callback` but having trouble implementing it for arrays of values rather individual values.

Is there a way to preserve the letter case in the match while maintaining an array of all lower case values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had more time there might be a more elegant solution, but here's a start:

```
foreach ($delta as $k => $v) {
    $pattern = '/\b(?<!\-)('.$k.')\b(?!-)/i';
    $result = preg_replace_callback($pattern,
                                    function($m) use($v){
                                        return (ucfirst($m[1]) == $m[1]) ? ucfirst($v) : $v;
                                    }, $str);
}
```

This will not account for all upper or mixed cases such as `AUTHORIZE` and `authORize` etc...

Comment: this worked! I will need to address for all caps as well but think I can figure it out now that I get have a good starting place. Thank you!!